# Can Chrome auto filter certificates on anything else but CN?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, ui-automation, client-certificates

We use the Selenium Chrome driver for automating tests of our web app. The app requires clients certificates for authentication, and all certificates are issued from the same issuer.

For autoselecting certificate in tests, we have successfully used the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls` registry setting for something like

`{"pattern":"https://theWebApp.com","filter":{"ISSUER":{"CN":"OurIssuerCN"}}}"`

Recently we added a new app, and in our tests for this one, we would ideally want Chrome to autoselect a different certificate, still from the same issuer, which the above pattern of course does not allow for.
To overcome this, we've tried adding friendly name and thumbprint to the filter part, but with no success.

Has anybody successfully managed to get Chrome to autoselect a certificate based on anything else but CN?